# Merge from one fork to another

Tags: git, github

I know there are quite a few similar questions but I couldn't find an existing answer that met my needs.

I have my own fork of a repo and have created a feature branch. I want Joes feature branch changes in my feature branch so I can continue working on the feature since Joe has moved on.

```
----+----+----+---+ Joes fork
    |         
    +--+--+--+--+ Joes feature branch


----+----+----+---+ My fork
                  |         
                  +--+ My feature branch
```

Since our feature branches are created from different commits Im just trying to get straight what my options are and what is generally the usual approach taken in this scenario.

Should I just merge from Joes feature branch to mine and deal with any conflicts? Or is it better practise to create my feature branch from the same commit as Joes feature branch and then merge across which should have no conflicts (until I update from my fork master perhaps).

Comment: If they are related to the same project, in order to understand the whole thing, you should set up that chart over a single tree. The thing is that, even if they are different repos, the branches would still be "the same", at least the common part.

Comment: You can add Joe's fork as another remote to your clone and checkout Joe's feature branch in your clone. From here on, you have several ways to take over Joe's code. I would rebase both branches to latest code, checkout one of them and merge the other. This way you need to deal with only conflicts between your files and Joe's files. Any conflict between latest and each feature branch are resolved during rebase step. Hope this helps!.

Comment: Do the origins of the branches ("My fork" and the commit where "Joes feature branch" forked from "Joes fork") relate to each other? If they part of same history then one of them should be a ancestor of the other